# Radio Type Toggle button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three custom buttons and they works like a radio.
I wanted to add something extra in this but I am not figuring out how .

There are three buttons currently (can be more) I can select only one . If I select any one color of the button will change and will show as it is active. I am wanting if I again click on this selected button this will unselect.

It should stay as a radio type but on addition I am wanting above requirement.

HERE is my **[JS fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6ByE5/1/)**

**JS**

```
    $('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function(){
    $('.toggleButtonRadio').removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you remove the `active` class before the toggle, so it doesn't remove it, you can change your code to this:

```
$('.toggleButtonRadio').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $('.toggleButtonRadio').not(this).removeClass("active");
});
```

**<kbd>[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/REyNH/)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks ! I was having some logical problem I guess :)